# Geolocation reporting location in South Atlantic Ocean

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

Code:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos){
    var lat = pos.coords.longitude;
    var lng = pos.coords.longitude;

    Location.address(lat, lng).then(function(address){
      address = address.results[0].address_compnents.formatted_address.split(',');

      var length = address.length,
          mid = Math.floor(length/2);

      $scope.requestData.address = {
          line1: address.slice(0,mid).join(',').trim(),
          line2: address.slice(mid,length).join(',').trim()
      };
    });
  }, function(){
    // Do nothing, they will have to enter address manually
  });
```

Every time it's run, `lat` and `lng` both return `-2.1065682000000003`, a seemingly random location in [the South Atlantic](https://www.google.com/search?q=-2.1065682000000003%2C-2.1065682000000003). However, this [demo](http://html5demos.com/geo) works fine. Any ideas why?

Comment: Why are you assigning the longitude to `var lat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos){
    var lat = pos.coords.longitude;
    var lng = pos.coords.longitude;
```

You are assigning the *longitude* value to *both* `lat` and `lng` here … d’oh!

> Every time it's run, lat and lng both return -2.1065682000000003

And that both had the *same* value didn’t make you think and look over your code more carefully to begin with …?

Answer (score 0):

var lat = pos.coords.longitude;
or 
var lat = pos.coords.latitude;